# How to change the background color in Drawer navigation in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I need to change the background color of the drawer screen. I am using react-navigation. Is there is an option to change this color? Refer the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using 3.x ,There is a prop named `overlayColor`.

Comment: How to change the height of the drawer navigator?  I need only a small drawer height

Comment: I am afraid that there is no height prop exist in drawer navigator .If must,You can implement a drawer by yourself.